# Backbone.Marionette model.destroy issue

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have very simple backbone model and collection. I have a corresponding backbone.marionette.CollectionView and backbone.marionette.ItemView and they live in a backbone.marionette.region.

The ItemView template contains a "remove" button. The click event of the remove button issues a model.destroy(). A HTTP DELETE is issued to the backend, but it appears to be issued twice and because the second time it fails, the item is not removed from the collection.

Everything else is working fine, just the HTTP DELETE being issued twice. Any idea why?

I'm using Backbone.Marionette version v0.4.5

```
# Model:
class User extends Backbone.Model
  idAttribute: "_id"

# Collection
class Users extends Backbone.Collection
  model: app.User 
  url: "/someUrl/Users"

# CollectionView 
class UserListView extends Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView
  tagName: "ul",
  itemView: app.UserItemView

# ItemView
class UserItemView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  template: "#item"
  tagName: "li"

  events:
    "click .edit": "edit"
    "click .remove": "remove"

  remove: ->
    @model.destroy()

  edit: (e) ->
    alert JSON.stringify @model
```

Comment: mhmm.... it really seemas something related to some built in event or method. Try to use non standard names for events and methods. For instance you could try to rename the remove method in 'myRename' (remove is a pre-defined backbone method in views and collections)

Comment: Daniele, you're absolutely correct. I had actually already worked out the solution (see my conversion with Derick Bailey at https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/issues/25). But if you would like to post your previous comment as an answer I will happily tick it as correct so you get the credit. Thanks again.

Comment: ok, I'm happy we foud the solution. The answer follows in the post. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mhmm.... it really seems something related to some built in event or method.

Try to use non standard names for events and methods.

For instance you could try to rename the remove method in 'myRename' (remove is a pre-defined backbone method in views and collections).

like this:

```
 # ItemView
 class UserItemView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
   template: "#item"
   tagName: "li"

   events:
     "click .edit": "edit"
     "click .remove": "myRemove"

   myRemove: ->
     @model.destroy()

   edit: (e) ->
     alert JSON.stringify @model
```

hope this helps

Comment: FWIW: this issue is now documented in the Marionette issues list, with a full explanation of why calling that method 'remove' caused it: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/issues/25

Comment: ...as the repo for Marionette has moved, so has the issue Derick links to; it's now at https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/25